# Java: Why can't I output a String converted from StringBuffer to the console in it's entirety?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer, system.out

When I debug the code below, in the "Variables" view, both `response` and `this.response` show the entire 1,779 lines of streamed input from http://www.google.com.  If, however, I want to output `this.response` to the console with `System.out.println(this.response.toString();`, it only outputs the last few lines.

Initially I thought it was a limitation of the `String` class. To test this I copied the 1,779 lines and assigned them to a test String variable.  When I output that test String variable, it output all 1,779 lines to the console just fine.

What am I missing where both `this.respponse` and `response` show the entire document, but when I go to output either of them, I only get the last few lines?

```
public class ClassC {
    private String url = "http://www.google.com";
    private URL URL;
    private HttpURLConnection con;
    private String response;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassC();
    }

    public ClassC() {
        try {
            URL = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) URL.openConnection();

            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = null;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
            rd.close();
            this.response = response.toString();
            System.out.println(this.response);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Using the same variable name twice and printing it within your while loop is a bit confusing.... anyway, I guess this has something to do with your terminal/console? which console are you writting to?

Comment: You're reprinting a lot of content with `System.out.println(response.toString());`

Comment: Is www.google.com the actually url you are reading. Some websites respond differently depending on what is accessing them. i.e. they may detect the user-agent type to enable/disable javascript for example.

Comment: Try `\n` instead of `\r`. `System.out.println("abcde\rfghi")` results in `fghie`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\n` instead of `\r`.

'\r' is a carriage return - it returns the caret to the start of the line, but doesn't start a new line, effectively overwriting the current line (or parts of it).

e.g. `System.out.println("abcde\rfghi")` results in `fghie`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation in Java that I am aware of with printing content. The issue could be with your console. Are you using Eclipse or some other IDE to develop and run the application? If so - then yes by default the older lines will be truncated on the Eclipse Run Console by default. Also the line is redundent,

```
this.response = response.toString();
```